# Consulta de API bloqueada por CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, apache, cors

Caros,

Estou realizando a chamada de uma API, porém está sendo bloqueada pelo CORS. Instalei uma extensão em meu navegador que habilita e desabilita o CORS. Quando habilito a API retorna os dados esperados, porém ao desativar retorna o seguinte erro no console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://minhaurldaapi/rest/busca?cod=1080' from origin 'http://17.12.4.127' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Código da chamada:

```
  var settings = {
    "url": "http://minhaurldaapi/rest/busca?cod=1080",
    "method": "GET",
     "crossDomain": true,
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
      "Authorization": "Basic AJeqpLOKkiifhueARIjcmOrij7FEF5iodUhIKCPERWh6"
    },
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  json = JSON.stringify(response);
  json2 = JSON.parse(json);

  });
```

Procurei em diversos outros tópicos problemas semelhantes, mas ainda não resolvi o problema. Alguém teria alguma ideia de como solucionar este impasse ? Seria alguma configuração no APACHE ?

Obrigado

Comment: Você configurou o cors na sua api?

Comment: @adventistaam A API é de um fornecedor externo... Estou apenas consultando... Poderia dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Então eles tem que configurar o CORS da api deles para aceitar o seu cliente

Comment: Se é uma API externa e ela não está configurada para ser consumida do seu frontend, você deve implementar em seu backend a comunicação com eles.

Comment: Você consegue acessar via postman ou Insomnia?

Comment: Sim, via Postman consegui acessar sem problemas.

Comment: Muito provavelmente a api deve estar bloqueando a origem e porta de sua api

Comment: Tenta seguir essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813910/6754506), volte sua atenção para o headers

Comment: Adicionei ao headers as seguintes informações:
         `code` "accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode solicitar ao dono da API para incluir a chave `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` no cabeçalho de resposta com o endereço do seu domínio ou um `*`. Exemplo:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://seudominio.com` ou `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Com isto o **navegador** irá identificar a chave e não apontará mais o problema de CORS.

Caso isto não seja possível, você pode construir um proxy em seu backend (mesmo domínio) para intermediar estas requisições. Em outras palavras, seu frontend efetua a requisição ao seu backend, seu backend efetua a requisição a API e devolve a resposta.

Vou deixar este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) que na minha opinião dá vários detalhes sobre problemas como este.